# I have two 3dtext, one plays the animation, the other reverses it. After one go, the animation wont play anymore, why?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a 3dtext named Play, which when clicked will play the animation; the other one is named Back, which reverses the animation. Problem is after I Played and Backed it, the animation wont play anymore when i clicked Play.

The animation named redsubmenu is in legacy and clamp forever wrap mode.

```
    public class PlayButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {

        //public static PlayButtonScript pbs;
        public GameObject redsubmenu;

        void Update(){
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&&Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit)){
                if(hit.collider.name == "Play"){
                    redsubmenu.animation.Play();
                }
            }
    #endif


        }
    }


     public class BackButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {


        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&&Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if(hit.collider.name == "Back"){
                    transform.parent.animation["redsubmenu"].speed = -1;
                    transform.parent.animation.Play("redsubmenu");
                }
        }

    #endif
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you never reset the speed of the animation back to 1. When you click play the first time the speed is initially 1, so it works fine. However, when you back you set the speed to -1 and it is never set to any other value.

Try using:

```
if (hit.collider.name == "Play") {
    transform.parent.animation["redsubmenu"].speed = 1;
    redsubmenu.animation.Play();
}
```

in your play button script.

You might also be able to make use of Animation.Rewind.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Rewind.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more specific, i edited my playbuttonscript as shown below:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&&Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit)){
        if(hit.collider.name == "Play"){
            if(redsubmenu.animation["redsubmenu"].speed == -1){
                redsubmenu.animation["redsubmenu"].speed = 1;
            } else {
                redsubmenu.animation.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

in my back button, i delete the transform.parent.animation.Play, no need for that.